# How to increase the number of processing HTTP requests?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-web-api

I have ASP.NET Web API app (backend for mobile) published on Azure. Most of requests are lightweight and processed fast. But every client makes a lot of requests and do it rapidly on every interaction with mobile application.

The problem is that web application can't process even small (10/sec) amount of requests. Http queue growth but CPU doesn't.

I ran load testing with 250 requests/second and avg response time growth from ~200ms to 5s.

Maybe problem in my code? Or it's hardware restrictions? Can I increase count of processed requests at one time?

[image: Statistic for few active users]

[image: Http requests queue]

[image: CPU and Memory]

Answer (score 0):

First it really matters what instances do you use (specially if you use small and extra small instances), how many instances do you use - dont expect too much from 1 core and 2Gb RAM on server.

Use caching (WebApi.OutputCache.V2 to decrease servers processing efforts, Azure Redis Cache as fast cache storage), Database also can be a bottleneck.

If you`ll have same results after adding both more instances to server and caching - then you should take a look at your code and find bottlenecks there.

And thats only general recommendatins, there is no code in a question.

Comment: Is there any mean count of requests per second for instant types? Right now we use one S2 instance (2 cores, 3.5 gb ram)

Comment: about requests per second - if you using Visual Studio Online Load testing (.jmx) then you`ll get proper results, if you try to made load testing on servers from your local machine - then time might not be correct - your internet connection might be a bottleneck.

Comment: Try to add one more instance and take a look at load testing. But it really matters to test your server from the cloud (Like Visual Studio Online Load Tesing ) and not locally *via Jmeter*.

Comment: Also if you using Database - and probably you do (MS SQL), then set the database pricing tier to the corresponding S2 pricing tier. Otherwise database can slow down the server

Comment: and its really good idea to add OutputCache to the project http://www.strathweb.com/2012/05/output-caching-in-asp-net-web-api/
if you havn`t use it.

Comment: In the past I used Azure SQL but it really sucks. Now we have VM with SQL server and it processes a lot and fast. 

I tried to increase instances size to 5 and yes, it works fast. But I still worry that my code use hardware inefficiently.

p.s. used loader.io for tests

Comment: well - if adding instances helps - then its in your code. Some methods are really time consuming. There is no code in your question, so it`s up to you to find the bottleneck methods.

Comment: Am I right that it's ok that I have HTTP queue > 0 when CPU loading ~20%?

Comment: I have server with really heavy requests on Azure and my server handle 1k requests/second with maximum 5 - 8% at max because of the cache. So 20% disturbing sign

Comment: But in the other hand it can be acceptible for you if all requests are different and output caching cannot help you. That`s up to you to deside